# Where is the Bigquery load log I can look up after my code finished?

Tags: google-bigquery

I implemented a load job to update bigquery table using c#, however I found I cannot trace the log after the update finished.Once the job failed(especial for the upload data format/type problems) , the status still return "DONE" and I do not know if there is anything wrong with my upload data. Is there any log I can look up similar to job history log when I load data using web console?Or is there is any place I have get the information when my code finishes? Thanks.

Here is my loading code:

```
 var service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "BQ test"
                });

            var datasetRequest = service.Datasets.List(projectId);
            DatasetList datasetList = datasetRequest.Execute();

            var jobCollection = service.Jobs;

            var jobBody = new Job()
            {
                Id = projectId,
                Configuration = new JobConfiguration()
                {
                    Load = new JobConfigurationLoad()
                    {
                        //WriteDisposition = "WRITE_APPEND",
                        CreateDisposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
                        WriteDisposition = "WRITE_APPEND",
                        MaxBadRecords = 10,
                        SourceUris = new List<string> { "gs://myfiles/COMPANYIDFILE10.txt.csv" },
                        FieldDelimiter = "\t",
                        SourceFormat = "CSV",
                        AllowJaggedRows = true,
                        Schema = new TableSchema()
                        {
                            Fields = new List<TableFieldSchema>
                            {



                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "Timestamp",Type = "TIMESTAMP", Mode = "NULLABLE" },
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "ClientIpAddress",Type = "STRING",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "Username",Type = "STRING",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "GroupID",Type = "INTEGER",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "CompanyID",Type = "INTEGER",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "ProxyID",Type = "STRING",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "FullOrSiteLogging",Type = "STRING",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "PolicyFlags",Type = "STRING",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "ActionsTaken",Type = "STRING",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "ResponseStatus",Type = "INTEGER",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "ContentID",Type = "INTEGER",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "ContentType",Type = "STRING",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "BytesServed",Type = "INTEGER",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "RequestElapsedMs",Type = "INTEGER",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "CategoryId",Type = "INTEGER",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "MalwareType",Type = "STRING",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "MalwareName",Type = "STRING",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "Method",Type = "STRING",Mode = "NULLABLE"},
                                new TableFieldSchema() { Name = "Url",Type = "STRING",Mode = "NULLABLE"}
                            }
                        },
                        DestinationTable = new TableReference()
                        {
                            ProjectId = "ws-20150627-logs",
                            DatasetId = "CompanyGroup1",
                            TableId = "RawLogsTest2"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var respones = jobCollection.Insert(jobBody, projectId).Execute();
            //var jobId = jobBody.JobReference.JobId;
            while (true)
            {

                if (jobCollection.Get(projectId, respones.JobReference.JobId).Execute().Status.State == "DONE")
                {

                    return; 
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Wait");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you ["get" the job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get), a job that had an error will show up as `status.state` of `DONE`, as you note.  This means only that it's not running, whether successful or not.  An error is indicated right near there, in the `status.errorResult`.

The [Troubleshooting Errors](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors) page has some more detail.

Comment: The job actually is kind of running since the status changed from "PENDING" to "DONE". I have retrieved status.errorResult like below:
jobCollection.Get(projectId, respones.JobReference.JobId).Execute().Status.errorResult; but it returned "null" value to me.

Comment: Hm, if the job was DONE with no errorResult, that should indeed mean it succeeded.  Do you have an example job that did that?  ("project:id")